# Facebook and people you may know suggestions

Tags: privacy, facebook

I know all the conspiracy theories about if how you search for someone on it they can find out etc but I have a question.

We all know Facebook likes to keep its mining secret. Both mine and my daughters profiles have come up in the people you may know list on the account of somebody, whom I don't want knowing us.

We have no contact, we have no and never have had any contact on social media sites of any type with this person or members of their family, yet still we have come up on their feed.

The only link to put us together is a member of their family via WhatsApp and email and that is only me, not my daughter. Also this person of contact does not have a Facebook account.

My email account logged to my Facebook is not known by any member of their family and my mobile number is not known to Facebook in anyway.

The persons family all have iPhones which obviously sync with each other ref diary dates etc.. So do you think its possible that's its picked up by Facebook that way?  But that then doesn't explain how its picked up my daughter too or how it could link contact details which are not known by Facebook.

So, how does Facebook make this connection, and what can we do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, some of you are using WhatsApp. WhatsApp is owned by Facebook, and is allowed to look in your Contacts.

So as soon as two people use WhatsApp, Facebook may know that they are connected.

Other apps have access to your Contacts list as well. You may want to carefully consider which apps you use.
There are tools which allow you to limit the access that applications have to the data on your phone, but they usually require rooting / jailbreaking the device. This is by necessity; regular applications can't just hamper other applications, an application that does so needs to have more than normal permissions on your phone.